# Problem with regex: Unterminated character class

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I'm trying to escape the backslash character in my regex.

```
Validators.pattern('^[^\\]*$')
```

but it return me this error:

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[^\]*$/: Unterminated character class
```

I'm pretty sure my regex is good and I didn't see a solution in others similar topics.

Comment: *I'm pretty sure my regex is good* - yes, the `^[^\\]*$` regex *string* will work in online regex testers but your *string literal* is actually representing ``^[^\]*$`` - try that in any online regex tester. You escaped a `]` and the `[` is no longer closed. Use `Validators.pattern(/^[^\\]*$/)` instead.

Comment: If it's necessary to work with a string, you need to use a quadruple backslash, resulting in a string containing a double-backslash.